# Forcing an image download in PHP. Works locally but breaks on live Linux server

Tags: php, http, download

I am forcing the download of an image through my website.

Forced download works fine on Apache/Windows development machine.

However it pushes junk characters to the screen when live on my linux web server.

```
e.g. �����JFIF��H�H����6Exif��MM�*����
```

- Firefox - junk
- Chrome - junk
- Internet Explorer 7 - displays the image in the page

  ```
  $fileName = basename($filePath);
  $fileSize = filesize($filePath);


  // Output headers.
  header("Cache-Control: private");
  header("Content-Type: Image/jpeg");
  header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);


  // Output file.
  readfile ($filePath);                   
  exit();
  ```

**What differences might there be on my live server that would cause it to break?**

Comment: question, you want to force download yet to open the file in browser ? try download the file first, and open with image editing tools to check return file is valid

Comment: I think you meant [application/octet-stream](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-4.5.1).

Comment: I have changed my content type to Image/Jpeg but still get the same issue

Comment: See stillstanding's response below; using fifo you can automatically detect the correct mime type, which will make your life easier.

Comment: Try lowercase `image/jpeg`. I've never seen a mixed-case MIME type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hat tip (and +1) to [stillstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336508/stillstanding), who pointed out using [fifo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php), but I thought I'd provide an example here to help.  This example requires the fifo extension installed, and has been hacked out and slightly modified from some other code of mine.

```
    $filename = 'blarg.jpg';
    $filepath = '/foo/bar/blarg.jpg';
    $finfo    = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mime     = $finfo->file($file);

    // Provide a default type in case all else fails
    $mime = ($mime) ? $mime : 'application/octet-stream';

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-type: ' . $mime);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

    header('Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: cache');
    header('Cache-Control: private');
```

Comment: 1) There's no point in providing a default Content-Type. If you don't know it, leave it out. 2) There's no Content-Transfer-Encoding header in HTTP. 3) The Content-Disposition header will be illegal as soon as the the filename contains characters outside ISO-8859-1. See RFC2231/5987 for additional advice.

Comment: Thanks, will check that out.  Is there any suggested method for handling non ISO-8859-1 characters?  I just use this approach to encourage the browser to download images and videos, rather than displaying them inline.  Also, what is the downside to providing application/octet-stream as the default?

Comment: The recommended encoding for filename is described in RFC5987 and draft-ietf-httpbis-content-disposition (but it doesn't work in all browsers). A default of application/octet-stream is meaningless; there's no point to set it if you don't know the real encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You have an incorrect MIME type in the header. Use [`finfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) so you can send the correct one instead of transmitting everything as an `application/stream`, otherwise browser behavior will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the Content-Type be set to image?

Comment: Hi, I have tried this now but still has no affect. Is there anything else I can check?